# What is the meaning of foo::bar::baz() in C++?

Tags: c++

A simple question: if I have a line like this:

```
int foo::bar::baz() {...
```

How is this interpreted? baz() is the function name, but is 'foo' a class or a namespace? Is 'bar' a class or a subclass or what?

Comment: You have 3 possibilities. `foo` and `bar` are both classes or structs, `foo` is a namespace and `bar` is a class or struct, or both `foo` and `bar` are namespaces. In the first two, `baz()` is a member of `bar`. In the latter, it is a free function. So without seeing the declarations, you honestly don't know which it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `foo` and `bar` can be either namespaces or classes.

However, if `foo` is a class, then so is `bar`: you cannot have a namespace nested inside of a class.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something along those lines. :)

Answer (score 3):

'bar' is a nested class or struct. It could be nested in a namespace, class or struct called 'foo'.

Comment: `bar` can also be a namespace.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev only if `foo` is a namespace.